# making a histogram using a for loop

Tags: python

I seem to be having an issue when I try to obtain a histogram inside a for loop. Here's what my code looks like:

```
for i in channel_list:

    ch = int(i)
    channel_data = buf.getChannelData(ch)
    time_seq = buf.getTimeSequence(0.0)


    #specify the parameters here:

    aveChannel_data = np.mean(channel_data[0:100])
    calChannel_data = channel_data - aveChannel_data


    channel, up, low, mid, before, after= self.drop_time(ch,calChannel_data)
    fall_time = time_seq[low]- time_seq[before]
    rise_time = time_seq[after] - time_seq[low]

    plt.hist(fall_time, bins = 30)
```

[image: histogram I want]

But instead I get something like this:

[image: results I am getting]

It seems that for every iteration the new data keeps being plotted over the old data.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think you need to add to a list of data points within your iterations and then  plot it in the end, otherwise the overwrite will occur

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did as you advised and now it seems to work. In my data I have 12 channels of data and when I append my array inside the for loop, the only set of data is the last one. Is there a way to obtain a list of all the channels?

Comment: If you declare your list outside of your loop, and then append to the list inside the loop, your list will still be accessible outside of your loop. Did this answer your question?